# MudTable ColGroup not working when having more than 10 columns

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I used a MudTable to display data with 14 columns. I tried to set the width for some columns but none of them worked. I tried to comment on a few columns, and limit them to 4 columns and it worked.

```
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width: 60px;" />
        <col />
        <col />
        <col style="width: 100px;"/>
    </ColGroup>
```

I am not sure MudTable has any attribute affecting the ColGroup. How to set a specific width if you have more than 10 columns in a MudTable?

**Update:** I tried to set the width to max-content in the browser and it displayed correctly. However, when I set it in the code, the height gets out of the screen and scrollbars disappeared.

Comment: I tried with 20 columns by setting col width but works fine.

Comment: Create a reproducible example here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a div or span nested in  and set the width to that div for it to work. Problem solved.